# Which font is this? [see pictures]

Tags: fonts

I am sorry to ask a rather stupid question, but I was not sure where to ask or where to look.

Does someone know which font this is?
Especially the Greek and the calligraphic fonts?

[image]

[image]

Comment: If it comes from a PDF, then the fonts are listed in the PDF.

Comment: Or you can use a service like: https://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont - which will tell you that it's most probably Palatino. Maybe using https://www.ctan.org/pkg/newpx will help